# How to enable automatic google search for unknown URL?

Tags: firefox, browser

is there a way to enable the browser to perform a google search, if the string typed in the adress bar is not resolvable?

For example, if I type:

*stack over flow*

My Browser just says:

```
The address isn't valid
The URL is not valid and cannot be loaded.
```

I am aware of the keyword concept, for example setting g for google.com such that:

*g stack over flow*

would perform a google search.

But is it also possible to define something like a default search engine that just searchs the given string whenever the address can not be resolved?

I use **Firefox 16.0.1** for **Linux Mint**.

Thanks!

Comment: Firefox does support this, just type the search term in your address bar and it will search for you..

Comment: As I stated in the question this does not work. I get the error message above.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the keyword.URL setting in about:config. Info can be found here:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyword.URL

HTH
ysis